# Why wordlist is giving me only last result, but not all results?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm beginner in python trying to make a wordlist generator 
But I think I have wrong code indentation
Here is my code

```
import itertools
s=[ [ 'T', 't'], ['e', 'E', '3'], ['s', 'S', '$'], ['T', 't'], [' ', '_', '%'], ['3'] ]
out = (itertools.product(*s))
for index, entry in enumerate(out): result = ''.join(entry)
result = result.replace('%', '')
print(result)
```

It should work, but I think i have or i miss a space or enter

Answer (score 1):

`result = ''.join(entry)` replaces the contents of `result` in each iteration, so only the one from the last remains.

Comment: Not this is the problem. If I will remove this line I will have only last password too and I will have issues with blank space in symbols

Comment: Removing a problematic line isn't the only way to fix it; what do you *want* this line to do?

Comment: in this instance it doesn't like having an empty string in input set, hence the shenanigans with %